# FtpWebRequest through HTTP proxy - incomplete file list

Tags: c#, proxy, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I'm trying to list the files in a directory using ftp in c#, i have the following code:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
var reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(host + "/"));
reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
reqFTP.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy, proxyport)
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(proxyuser, proxypass, proxyuserdomain)
};
reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
reqFTP.UseBinary = false;
reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails; //also tried ListDirectory
using (var response = reqFTP.GetResponse())
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            result.Append(line);
            result.Append("\n");
            line = reader.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This returns a HTML response like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>FTP Listing of /foo/bar/ at my.ftpste.com</TITLE>
<BASE HREF="ftp://foo:bar@my.ftpste.com.com/foo/bar/">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H2>FTP Listing of /foo/bar/ at my.ftpste.com</H2>
<HR>
<A HREF="../">Parent Directory</A><BR>
<PRE>
Nov 01 2011 17:27         4356 <A HREF="File1.txt">File1.txt</A>
Oct 22 2010 00:00       275051 <A HREF="File2.txt">File2.txt</A>
Oct 25 2010 00:00         1875 <A HREF="File3.txt">File3.txt</A>
Oct 26 2010 00:00         2553 <A HREF="File4.txt">File4.txt</A>
</PRE>
<HR>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Note that the response is complete, including the closing html tag.

**The problem is that this list of files is not complete.** When i open the same url in internet explorer, using the same proxy, i see near identical HTML, except that there are more files listed (eg File5.txt, File6.txt). The same is true when i use a normal FTP client like filezilla.

I cannot understand why this is happening, any ideas?

Comment: try "while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))" instead of your while, just an idea.

Comment: @M.H: Thanks, i don't think this is the problem though, since the response is complete, note the `</HTML>` at the end which wouldn't be present if the loop terminated early.